# How to stop flake8 and pylint complaining about shebang line over max characters?

Tags: python, pylint, flake8

I am using flake8 and pylint via [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) in vim.

I know how to disable individual errors/warnings for each of these linters in their respective config files.

How can I keep the `line-too-long` checks *except* for the shebang line at the start of the file (if present)?

If the first line is not a shebang line, it should still complain about too-long lines.

So if the max line length is 5 (for sake of example), with this file:

```
#!/run/stuff
x=3
print(x)
```

They should complain about the third line but not the first one.

But with this file:

```
x = 1 + 1 + 1
# Print the result
print(x)
```

It should complain about all three lines.

Comment: There's no way to do that, but I'm sure pycodestyle and pylint would be open to suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to [Ian Stapleton Cordasco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953283/ian-stapleton-cordasco), I ended up submitting a patch to pycodestyle (which is used by flake8) to ignore the length of shebang lines.

So now to fix my ALE setup, I can replace the pycodestyle script my copy of flake8 is using with the [latest version from GitHub](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle), and disable line-too-long checks in pylint while leaving them on in flake8/pycodestyle. That way without modifying my scripts in any way I still get linting for line length everywhere else, without getting redundant warnings for long shebangs.

Answer (score 2):

Make a config file by doing `pylint --generate-rcfile`. see here for more https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html

under the `[MESSAGES CONTROL]` section add `line-too-long` to the list of for `disable=`.

On the second line of each python file, you re-enable `line-too-long`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env                python3
# pylint: enable=line-too-long
x=3
print(x) # make this longer than the enable line
```

I set the line limit to 30, so pylint complains about line 4. I added gratuitous whitespace to the shebang line, but the length is still overlooked by pylint.